# Eloquent Eager loading & eager saving

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a function, when a group is updated with training/users, it cycles through all the training a user is currently assigned and adds any missing training for them.

I am using Laravel's Eloquent.

I am wondering, is there a way that I can eager load the '$user_list' so that I am not performing several queries? Same with the create, is there an option for some kind of bulk create? My function is below.

```
public function assignTraining($group, $users)
{
    $group_list = $group->trainings()->get();
    $data = [];

    foreach ($users as $user_id){

        $data['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $user_list = User::find($user_id)->trainings()->get();
        $training_list = $group_list->diff($user_list)->lists('id');

        foreach ($training_list as $training_id){

            $data['training_id'] = $training_id;
            Note::create($data);
        }
    }
}
```

As for the relationship,

- Users is many to many with Groups (pivot table is "group_user").
- Groups is many to many with Training (pivot table is "group_training").
- Users is many to many with Training ("Notes" is the pivot
  table name).

Users and Training can both be part of a group. They can even be part of the same group. Also many users can be assigned to many different trainings.

Comment: Can you explain the relations a bit more?

Comment: I updated my original question with the relationship. I hope it helps.